# Access a shared folder(which is protected)

Tags: c#, impersonation

I need help in writing a C# script which can access a secured shared location(i hv the username and password) in order to access some files from that location and also dump some files over there pragmatically.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access a network share that is protected you need to call LogonUser and do impersonation within your application. The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) provides a code sample.  Then you can just browse, copy/move, etc with the System.IO namespace.  For instance:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFolders(@"\\Server\Share");
```

will return a list of the folders on the network share.

Answer (score 0):

I take it the app will be running under credentials different than the username/password that can access the folder.

You can use impersonation, see this question for how to set up the win32 api calls to logon and revert to self.

[Impersonate user in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505231/impersonate-user-in-codebehind)