# How to read shared file from Ubuntu/Samba using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, ubuntu, shared-file

I have shared folder on ubuntu/samba server of my network.

I am running my c# code on Vista , so How can i read file shared on ubuntu/samba server ?

My code :

```
String errorLogFile = @"\\\\198.168.0.2\\sharedfolder\myfile.wmv";

//throws excetion login fail
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(errorLogFile);

sr.Read();

streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem/error? What is ubantu and sambha (rhetorical)? With 15k rep mostly from answers you should value a good question!

Comment: think you mean ubuntu and samba?

Comment: @ Daniel - yes its ubuntu and samba ... i tried to read file as we do on windows machine but it shows no file exists...

Comment: y -1 ? is anything wrong with question ?

Comment: @Daniel - okies anyway it resolve my issue ............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c/5433640#5433640) to authenticate your code for the remote directory.

Update:
Additionally, the combination of escaped backslashes and verbatim strings is a bad idea. Use one of these but not both.
Also, you are missing the backslash after the name of the shared folder.
It should be like this:

```
String errorLogFile = @"\\198.168.0.2\sharedfolder\" + finaldate + ".wmv";
```

Answer (score 2):

If the share is configured properly you should be able to access it via `\\ubuntumachine\sambasharename` just as you would a Windows share.

Comment: i am doing it but its says "Login fail".. how to avoid it...is i have to use winows impersonation ??

Comment: So you are probably using the wrong login credentials. Verify those first before suspecting your code is incorrect.

Comment: @Cody Gray - if i use windows impersonation libaray will it work for unbuntu ??