# In my C# application, I have to read the content of a file that is in the file system of a remote Linux OS Machine. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, linux, xml, file, streamreader

I have a C# application that is running on a Win2019 Server. In my application I have to read out the file content of a xml file in a remote CNC production machine. There is an ethernet connection to the remote CNC machine and I can ping it without problem.

If it would be Windows, I could use streamreader for it.
But the CNC machine (IPC) has Linux OS. How can I read the file content of this file? Is it possible to use streamreader also?

In the internet it is recommended to use some software tools, but I couldn't find a solution yet, that I can implement directly in my C# project.

Comment: Could you perhaps use SSH?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177916/how-to-read-shared-file-from-ubuntu-samba-using-c

Comment: Linux you can create a window partition.  Then window partition can be a network drive on a window machine.  Using a URI for the file you can also read in c# using XDocument or XmlReader instead of using a streamreader.