# Need Impersonation when accessing shared network drive

Tags: c#, impersonation

When I tried to access network drive file from local its working fine but when i deploy the code I am getting bellow error

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>
> at System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteFile(String filename, Boolean readIntoMemory)
>
> at System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteFile(String filename)
>
> at Configs.gvConfigs_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) in C:\Users\bpucha1103c\Desktop\CellBackHaul_Publish\Configs.aspx.cs:line 59
>   2013-02-05 13:31:21,412 [19] WARN  System.Web.UI.Page [(null)] - Logging:System.IO.IOException: The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server.

how to do impersonation when accessing the file in network shared folder? Below is my code

```
GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
LinkButton lnkTxtFile = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkTxtFile");
string strFilename = lnkTxtFile.Text.Replace("/","\\");
System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilename);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
//HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.End();
```

here is my modified code

```
GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
LinkButton lnkTxtFile = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkTxtFile");
string strFilename = lnkTxtFile.Text.Replace("/", "\\");
System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilename);
RunOperationAsUser(() =>
{
  //GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
  //LinkButton lnkTxtFile = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkTxtFile");
  //string strFilename = lnkTxtFile.Text.Replace("/", "\\");
  //System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilename);
  Response.Clear();
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name);
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
  //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
  Response.End();
}, "bpucha1103c", targetFile.DirectoryName , "White1234");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access a Remote Directory from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I am able to download the file for firsttime..when I am trying to do second time I am getting error like " Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again"....even if i dispose the connection after download its not working..

Comment: Which code are you using? The one from the other question I linked?

Comment: I tried your code.. the one you provided...

Comment: Are you sure you dispose the first `NetworkConnection` instance before you create the next?

Comment: i just used your code and after the file is downloaded i just used NetworkConnection.dispose in my final block. still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use the following code to impersonate as another user and run an action:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr existingTokenHandle, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr duplicateTokenHandle);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool RevertToSelf();
[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LoadUserProfile(IntPtr hToken, ref ProfileInfo lpProfileInfo);

[DllImport("Userenv.dll", CallingConvention =
    CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool UnloadUserProfile
    (IntPtr hToken, IntPtr lpProfileInfo);

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
public static extern int CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr pVoid, int
    cAuthSvc, IntPtr asAuthSvc, IntPtr pReserved1, RpcAuthnLevel level,
    RpcImpLevel impers, IntPtr pAuthList, EoAuthnCap dwCapabilities, IntPtr
    pReserved3);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ProfileInfo
{
    ///
    /// Specifies the size of the structure, in bytes.
    ///
    public int dwSize;

    ///
    /// This member can be one of the following flags: 
    /// PI_NOUI or PI_APPLYPOLICY
    ///
    public int dwFlags;

    ///
    /// Pointer to the name of the user.
    /// This member is used as the base name of the directory 
    /// in which to store a new profile.
    ///
    public string lpUserName;

    ///
    /// Pointer to the roaming user profile path.
    /// If the user does not have a roaming profile, this member can be NULL.
    ///
    public string lpProfilePath;

    ///
    /// Pointer to the default user profile path. This member can be NULL.
    ///
    public string lpDefaultPath;

    ///
    /// Pointer to the name of the validating domain controller, in NetBIOS format.
    /// If this member is NULL, the Windows NT 4.0-style policy will not be applied.
    ///
    public string lpServerName;

    ///
    /// Pointer to the path of the Windows NT 4.0-style policy file. 
    /// This member can be NULL.
    ///
    public string lpPolicyPath;

    ///
    /// Handle to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key.
    ///
    public IntPtr hProfile;
}

public enum RpcAuthnLevel
{
    Default = 0,
    None = 1,
    Connect = 2,
    Call = 3,
    Pkt = 4,
    PktIntegrity = 5,
    PktPrivacy = 6
}

public enum RpcImpLevel
{
    Default = 0,
    Anonymous = 1,
    Identify = 2,
    Impersonate = 3,
    Delegate = 4
}

public enum EoAuthnCap
{
    None = 0x00,
    MutualAuth = 0x01,
    StaticCloaking = 0x20,
    DynamicCloaking = 0x40,
    AnyAuthority = 0x80,
    MakeFullSIC = 0x100,
    Default = 0x800,
    SecureRefs = 0x02,
    AccessControl = 0x04,
    AppID = 0x08,
    Dynamic = 0x10,
    RequireFullSIC = 0x200,
    AutoImpersonate = 0x400,
    NoCustomMarshal = 0x2000,
    DisableAAA = 0x1000
}

const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
const int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL = 2;

public void RunOperationAsUser(Action operation, string userName, string domain, string password)
{
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr dupToken = IntPtr.Zero;

    //Impersonate the user
    if (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token))
    {
        if (DuplicateToken(token, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref dupToken))
        {

            WindowsIdentity newIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(dupToken);
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newIdentity.Impersonate();

            int retCode = CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr.Zero, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
                RpcAuthnLevel.PktPrivacy, RpcImpLevel.Impersonate, IntPtr.Zero, EoAuthnCap.DynamicCloaking, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (impersonatedUser != null)
            {
                var username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).Name;
                var sid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).User.Value;

                ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
                profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                profileInfo.lpUserName = userName;
                profileInfo.dwFlags = 1;

                Boolean loadSuccess = LoadUserProfile(dupToken, ref profileInfo);
            }

            operation();

            impersonatedUser.Undo();
        }
    }
    if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        CloseHandle(token);
    }
    if (dupToken != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        try
        {
            CloseHandle(token);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

now you can do

```
RunOperationAsUser(() => {
    GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    LinkButton lnkTxtFile = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkTxtFile");
    string strFilename = lnkTxtFile.Text.Replace("/","\\");
    System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilename);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
    //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    Response.End();
}, userName, domain, password)
```

Comment: what about the methods like LogonUser,DuplicateToken? what do i need to specify in that?

Comment: Ups, sorry about that, these are some DllImports you need to reference

Comment: can you which dlls i need reference for methods like LogonUser,DuplicateToken.

Comment: You can see in my answer, I have updated my code - "advapi32.dll"

Comment: do i need to change anything web.config and iss level? like set impersonation = "true"??

Comment: I am getting error like ex = {"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.\r\n"}.. but I am passing right values..

Comment: Wow!! It worked!  What a great piece of code. +1 and a humble thank you!