# FileIOPermission error saving file

Tags: c#, file-io, file-permissions

My problem is that this `try` fails (resulting in the catch) on only one computer, even using the same user account. It runs fine and saves screenshots from every other computer that uses the program.

Also, manually saving a file (through explorer) into the directory works.

```
try
{
    Bitmap screenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)screenShot);
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));

    imageSavePath = @"\\navy\data\Docs\PRE\LogSite\Screenshots\" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-') + ".png";
    screenShot.Save(imageSavePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error saving screenshot\n\n" + e.ToString());
}
```

This is the error:
[image: Error Image]

EDIT: The exe is running from a network drive

Comment: instead of showing the whole exception message, show the imagepath. Would be a lot more useful

Comment: In the MessageBox? the thing is it works on other computers consistently, so how could that be a problem?

Comment: I think the application may not have permission to write to the folder, have you tried running as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I have edit my answer. Base on the code, you are trying save to Network share folder I believe you should use impersonate to resolve permission issue.

Please reference the link below.

[Need Impersonation when accessing shared network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753766/need-impersonation-when-accessing-shared-network-drive)

Comment: how? FileIOPermission has absolutely nothing to do with how its saved

Comment: There have only been problems on this computer. Many other computers (Using the same user) running the same code work fine.