# How to restart service remotely?

Tags: c#, service, wmi, arcgis, wmi-service

I can start or stop service remotely from .net project.

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = @"192.168.36.22\test";
options.Password = "test";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\192.168.36.22\root\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();


ManagementOperationObserver Stop = new ManagementOperationObserver();
Stop.Completed += new CompletedEventHandler(Stop_CallBack);
try
{
    string NameServices = "ArcGIS Server";
    WqlObjectQuery query = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service  WHERE Name=\"" + NameServices + "\"");
    ManagementObjectSearcher find = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    foreach (ManagementObject spooler in find.Get())
    {
        spooler.InvokeMethod("StopService", new object[] { });
        spooler.InvokeMethod(Start, "StopService", new object[] { });
    }
 }
....
```

How can I restart this service?

Comment: You can use stop and then start. It is the same.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use the ServiceController class like so:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ArcGIS Server", "192.168.36.22");

sc.Start();
sc.Stop();
```

This saves you having to write all that code to interact with WMI.  Note to use the ServiceController class, you'll have to add a reference to the System.ServiceProcess assembly.

Comment: Can I restart service using ManagementObject?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to use ManagementObject then you just need to pass "StartService" to InvokeMethod

Comment: When I use ServiceController, I have exception "Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'MAPSERVER'. This operation might require other privileges"

Comment: How does this solution work without username and password for the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

Service controller didn't work for me, so I used Cmd to do it.

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C sc \\\\remoteMachine stop \"serviceName\"&sc \\\\remoteMachine start \"serviceName\"");
```

To overcome credentials issue, I used class from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433640/2179222 answer.

So in the end It looked like this:

```
    private static void RestartService(string remoteMachine, string serviceName, string userName, string password)
    {
        using (new NetworkConnection($"\\\\{remoteMachine}", new NetworkCredential(userName, password)))
        {
            Process.Start("CMD.exe", $"/C sc \\\\{remoteMachine} stop \"{serviceName}\"&sc \\\\{remoteMachine} start \"{serviceName}\"");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can the `remoteMachine` be an IP address?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me with IP address as well

Answer (score -5):

I have come across a similar problem when I tried to connect, just add your machine name as admin in the 'users' group of the target machine and you will be able to fetch the data.