# C# run powershell script (remote start/stop service)

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access

In C# I have a script, that remotely stops and start service.
The problem is, only work stop service.

I need start/stop service, because service must be stopped for something else.
It may not be ServiceController, because I have disabled WMI.

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddCommand("Get-Service"); //STOP
ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", textBox7.Text);
ps.AddParameter("Name", "spooler*");
ps.AddCommand("Stop-Service");
ps.AddParameter("force");

//ps.AddCommand("Remove-Item"); //QUEUE

ps.AddCommand("Get-Service"); //START
ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", textBox7.Text);
ps.AddParameter("Name", "spooler*");
ps.AddCommand("Start-Service");

ps.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the solution:
Only need Add.Statement between commands.

```
            ps.AddCommand("Get-Service");
            ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", textBox7.Text);
            ps.AddParameter("Name", "spooler*");
            ps.AddCommand("Stop-Service");
            ps.AddParameter("force");

            ps.AddStatement();
            ps.AddCommand("Get-Service");
            ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", textBox7.Text);
            ps.AddParameter("Name", "spooler*");
            ps.AddCommand("Start-Service");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ServiceController class like so:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ArcGIS Server", "192.168.36.22");

sc.Start();
sc.Stop();
```

credits goes to:
[How to restart service remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405884/how-to-restart-service-remotely)

Comment: Cite question: "**It may not be ServiceController**, because I have disabled WMI. "