# Impersonate no error but token is 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, impersonation

I used a dll from this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14358/User-Impersonation-in-NET
Now what I'm trying to do is to access the remote directory and get its files. Whenever i tried doing this there is no error but when I'm trying to debug it the impersonation is null and there are no token so maybe you can give me insights about this tnx!.

```
ImpersonateUser imp = new ImpersonateUser();
try
{
    imp.Impersonate("bla", "bla", "bla");
    try
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\servername\folder", "*.txt");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);

        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what token is 0? Why do you try to impersonate yourself on localmachine and get localfiles, but in question mentioned remote folder?

Comment: @ilyaBursov oh i see.. what would be the proper path for the directorygetfiles?

Comment: checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp?lq=1

Comment: @ilyaBursov tnx for that now Im trying to access C\test but it says network not found can you help me about this?..

Comment: @ilyaBursov this is the format i did @"\\servername\test" still network found

Comment: my telepathy cannot reach you, how do you trying to access? did you follow instructions from answer, can you access it via windows explorer, what exactly error message and error code...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @ilyaBursov Ok the dll that I downloaded is not working for me so i get a class instead and it shows error on unknown username of password the thing is I can see what wrong right now tnx btw

Comment: There are tons of low quality articles on CodeProject, which even fail to mention what are the permissions required by the executing account, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx#paght000023_impersonatingbyusingwindowsidentity