# Accessing remote folder from win form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, shared-directory

I am developing a winform application on C# where I need to access a network folder but i get logon user password exception. How can i provide user credentials through application?

```
double length = ((Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.50.107\Destination", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(t => (new FileInfo(t).Length)) / 1024) / 1024) / 1024;
```

Comment: Go and research impersonation.

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using (new NetworkConnection(@"\\192.168.50.107\Destination", readCredentials))
using (new NetworkConnection(@"\\192.168.50.107\Destination", writeCredentials)) {
   double length = ((Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.50.107\Destination", "*",    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(t => (new FileInfo(t).Length)) / 1024) / 1024) /   1024;
}
```

Font: [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Comment: there is probably no need for writecredentials in this case

Comment: @Gabriel Bernardone I tried your code with helpm of
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp)
but it gives error .. "the network name can not be found"

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void ConnectToNetwork()
    {
        NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(@"UserName", "Password");
        CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
        theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\NAS"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
    }
```

Comment: Call this method before trying to access the file on the network.

Comment: And I noticed while doing this for my Project that the networkcredential didnt like when i used the IP address. So I used the name of IP instead and it works for me.

Comment: I tried in both ways.. with IP and with server name but it still gives error path not found..
`theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\192.168.50.107"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);`

Comment: Maybe you need to check your network credentials for the user you are trying to log in with. You should have read and write privileges