# Trying to read a file from UNC share - "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

Tags: c#, .net, unc

I have a file share on a remote PC, read only, **guest access is on**. I'm trying to read a file from that share via its UNC path, from a desktop app, using the code like this: `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\someservser\someshare\somefile.txt");`, but getting the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070569
  Message=Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.

  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string) in __error.cs
    System.IO.FileStream.Init(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, int, bool, System.IO.FileShare, int, System.IO.FileOptions, Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, string, bool, bool, bool) in filestream.cs
    System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, int, System.IO.FileOptions, string, bool, bool, bool) in filestream.cs
    System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(string, bool) in file.cs
```

I can open this file from Windows UI without any problem (same user as used to run the failing app).
Any ideas?

Comment: The error in code not even mentioned in the question - I bet you trying to do it from server side code. Please [edit] question with details... (or delete you are not the first on to hit "ntlm one hop hell")

Comment: Are you running the program with Administrator rights? I often lose access to network shares from within a program when I run it as Administrator.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov it has nothing to do with any kind of ASP.Net at all.

Comment: @Greg no, simple non-elevated app.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the approach below (with credentials)

```
using (new NetworkConnection(@"\\someservser\someshare", readCredentials)){
   var s = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\server\read\file\somefile.txt");
}
```

and [check this address for NetworkConnection implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433640/1118978)

**EDIT:** for the "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.” error, try the steps below

- On the Telnet server, open the Group Policy Management Editor. To do
  so, click Start, then in the Start Search box, type gpedit.msc, and
  then press ENTER.
- If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the
  action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.
- In the navigation pane, open Computer Configuration, Windows
  Settings, Security Settings, Local Policies, and User Rights
  Assignment.
- In the details pane, double-click Allow log on locally.
- Click Add User or Group.

another option is to give access to everyone user so that you won't need to login.

but again the best way is to create a local account for this particular purpose

Comment: It fails on the call to WNetAddConnection2

Comment: It's just the same.

Comment: PS specifying another user works with this approach, but using Guest account doesn't.

Comment: are you supposed to use Guest account? this generally doesn't make sense. The usage of Guest account is very very rare

Comment: I need to access the share with no special user account specified and with no password. AFAIR this gives only 2 choices - same account on both PCs, or Guest account.